# find time complexity j+=sqrt(i))

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, time-complexity

```
int x = 0; 
for (int i=1; i < n ; i++) { 
  for (double j=i; j <= n ; j+=sqrt(i)) { 
    ++x; 
  } 
}
```

I know that the outer loop does n iterations and the inner loop does n-1 iterations so I need to calculate time complexity of this loops.
Assume sqrt() runs in O(1).

thanks all.

Comment: You're almost there.. look at your question, the answer is hidden there.

Answer (score 1):

```
for...N
  for...N-1
    sqrt...1
    += ....1
```

The final complexity would be N x (N-1) * 1 or O(N<sup>2</sup>).